# AngularJS - Getting value of radio inputs where multiples exist

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to build an extension to a form using AngularJS whereby a series of set, fixed values pre-exist, whose values correspond to parameters which are passed through to a controller. Once these five, fixed values are set and present, custom options may be present which should use the same values, for which I'm using `ng-repeat` for.

I've got my values returning correctly, however by design, multiple checkboxes exist with the same value, which obviously causes all the inputs with the same value to select when selecting any one individual radio button.

My *initial* code being used to generate the form is as follows:

```
<form class="form_report form_performanceReport" data-ng-submit="performance.createReport(performance.save)">
    <fieldset class="form_report-reportType">
        <legend>Select a report type</legend>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="grades" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                Grade
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="weights" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" >
                Weight
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="calendar" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" >
                Calendar of supply
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="post-mortem" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                Postmortem
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="deadweight-gains" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                Dead weight gain
            </label>

            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports">
                <input type="radio" value="{{report.type}}" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                {{report.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Edited for brevity... -->
</form>
```

which gives me resulting HTML of:

```
<div class="elements">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="grades" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="7">
                Grade
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="weights" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="8">
                Weight
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="calendar" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="9">
                Calendar of supply
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="post-mortem" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="10">
                Postmortem
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="deadweight-gains" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="11">
                Dead weight gain
            </label>

            <!-- ngRepeat: report in performance.reports -->
            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                <input type="radio" value="weights" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="18">
                Test save report
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: report in performance.reports -->

            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                <input type="radio" value="grades" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="20">
                Test save report
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: report in performance.reports -->

            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                <input type="radio" value="weights" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="22">
                Test save report
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: report in performance.reports -->

            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                <input type="radio" value="deadweight-gains" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="24">
                Custom DWG report
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: report in performance.reports -->

            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                <input type="radio" value="post-mortem" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="26">
                Test Postmortem report
            </label>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: report in performance.reports -->
        </div>
```

...and I've made a stab at updating the values so they don't clash with the following code, which does alleviate the issue insofar as the radio buttons are now isolated in scope and only one selects at a time, due to the `number_` prefix on each input's `value` attribute:

```
<form class="form_report form_performanceReport" data-ng-submit="performance.createReport(performance.save)">
    <fieldset class="form_report-reportType">
        <legend>Select a report type</legend>

        <div class="elements">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="1_grades" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                Grade
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="2_weights" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" >
                Weight
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="3_calendar" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type" >
                Calendar of supply
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="4_post-mortem" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                Postmortem
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="5_deadweight-gains" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                Dead weight gain
            </label>

            <label data-ng-repeat="report in performance.reports">
                <input type="radio" value="{{$index+6}}_{{report.type}}" data-ng-model="performance.searchParams.type">
                {{report.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- Edited for brevity... -->
</form>
```

My controller which handles all these inputs has a block with the following:

```
vm.searchParams = {
  datefrom: $state.params.datefrom ? new Date($state.params.datefrom) : void 0,
  dateto: $state.params.dateto ? new Date($state.params.dateto) : void 0,
  lot: $state.params.lot,
  site: $state.params.site || constants.DEFAULT_ANY,
  type: $state.params.type || constants.DEFAULT_TYPE,
  name: $state.params.name
};
```

Essentially, I'm looking for some way to get the `value` attribute of the 'custom' reports, so a user can select only one radio button at any one time (so they should all have unique values), but when passed to the controller, the values should all be the same (so `6_weights` should be passed as `weights`, `7_grades` should be passed through as `grades` etc.).

Could this be done with a filter and Regex? I've already got a filter established which formats dates to the correct format used by the API I'm interacting with, which looks as follows:

```
function searchParamsFilter($filter, constants) {
  return function(params) {
    // Create a copy of the params, omit empty or default
    var filteredParams = {};
    for (var i in params) {
      if (params[i] && params[i] !== '' && params[i] !== constants.DEFAULT_ANY && params[i] !== constants.DEFAULT_ANY_ID.name && params[i] !== constants.DEFAULT_ANY_ID.id) {
        filteredParams[i] = params[i];
      }
    }

    // Correct the date format for API and querystring
    if (filteredParams.hasOwnProperty('datefrom')) {
      filteredParams.datefrom = $filter('date')(new Date(filteredParams.datefrom), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }
    if (filteredParams.hasOwnProperty('dateto')) {
      filteredParams.dateto = $filter('date')(new Date(filteredParams.dateto), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    }

    return filteredParams;
  };
}
```

I'm relatively new to Angular and its workings, so any help here would be very much appreciated!